# Magento 2.4.5-P1 AlertProcessor - Notification of product back in stock is not received

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.3, magento2.4.4, magento2.4.5

AlertProcessor - Notification of product back in stock is not received

Preconditions and environment
Magento version 2.4.5-P1
PHP8.1

**Expected result**
Alert stock email being sent

**Actual result**
Emails not triggered for Product Alerts.

**Steps to Reproduce**

- Enable product alert stock (Configuration > Catalog >Product Alerts > Allow Alert When Product Comes Back in Stock > Yes)
- Reindex and cache flush
- Front end
- Login as customer - Select a Product without stock - Register to a product stock alert
- Launch consumers

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked for me:

Adding the consumer alert_product in the **.magento.env.yaml** file:

[image]

Check before Code:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Communication/etc/communication.xsd">
    <topic name="product_alert" request="Magento\AsynchronousOperations\Api\Data\OperationInterface">
        <handler name="productAlert" type="Magento\ProductAlert\Model\Mailing\Consumer" method="process"/>
    </topic>
</config>
```